# How can I unify file permission differences between branches?

Tags: git

I've messed something up and I'm not quite sure how, or how to fix it. I have branch A and branch B, with A having what I've been working on. For some reason, the file permissions for numerable files that I didn't intend to change are different in my branch A. Branch B has the intended file permissions for all of those files. Is there a way I can get git to set it so that files where the only difference between A and B is the permissions, are set to the permissions as found in B?

In short, I kind of want to have B replace A, keeping only my intended file additions, deletions, and modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no handy built in solution for this, but it's easy to script: Git has a large tool-set that you can draw upon.

First, though, let's establish some background information.  You're not sure how this all came about, so there's a good chance it will happen again, and this time you can nip it in the bud (and figure out what did it).  If you want to jump straight to a potential solution, zip down to the bottom section.

1. Git stores commits.  You probably already know that, but let's just write it down. :-)  Each commit is uniquely identified by some big ugly hash ID, `deadcab1feeddad2...` or whatever.  These commits, once made, can never be changed.  Each commit has some metadata—such as your name and email address and a time stamp, and your log message, and also stores the raw hash ID of its *parent* commit (or for merge commits, both/all parents).
2. Commits store files, as a snapshot of every file that was in Git's *index* at the time you ran `git commit`.  The index is the reason you have to keep running `git add`.  The files stored in the commit are in a special, Git-only, compressed form where they're frozen for as long as the commit exists.

   When you check out some commit, Git extracts the entire snapshot into the index, so that the index now matches the commit.<sup>1</sup>  That "un-freezes" the files: once they are in the index, you can *change* them.  But they are still in the special Git-only format.  So now Git extracts the index into the work-tree, turning the files into their useful form.

   Files in the *work-tree* have permissions.  Files in the *index* have just one single permission-indicating bit, namely: *Should this file be executable?*  For historical (and Linux) reasons, Git presents this as `mode 100644`, "not executable", or `mode 100755`, "executable", but it really only allows the one flag bit.  The *rest* of the work-tree permissions come from whatever you have set for your system / yourself when you extract the files.

   When you run `git add` on a file, you are really telling Git: *Copy the work-tree file into the index copy.*  This Git-ifies the data, making it ready to be frozen into a commit.  It also sets the mode based on whether the file is currently executable.

   Normally, `git diff` will tell you if there's a mode-change from 100644 to 100755 or vice versa, so you can use `git diff` to compare.  Since there are *three* copies of each file—committed, indexed, and work-tree—you need *two* `git diff`s to find all the changes:

   - What's different between the commit and the index?
   - What's different between the index and the work-tree?

   You can run `git diff --cached` or `git diff --staged` to get the first set, and `git diff` with no options at all to get the second set.  (Note that if the executable mode has changed, Git will consider the file to be changed.)  The `git status` command runs *both* diffs, but summarizes them in a way that does not show the mode explicitly.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not entirely accurate (see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for details), but helps as the starting mental model.

---

> Branch B has the intended file permissions for all of those files.

We also need a little detour here about the fact that branches don't mean that much in Git.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452).)

In Git, a branch *name*—I'll use `branch-A` and `branch-B` here for the two names—simply identifies *one specific commit*.

I mentioned above that each commit has a unique hash ID.  Multiple *names* can have the same hash ID, though.  That's how new branches start out, in fact.  Meanwhile each commit "points back" to its parent, which is how a new branch starts out:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

Here, there's just the one branch, `master`.  It has the hash ID of commit `C`.  This is the *last* commit contained within the branch (and also the last commit in the repository, in this case).  Meanwhile commit `C` remembers the hash ID of `B`, which remembers the ID of `A`.  `A` is the very first commit, so it has no parent and the action stops here.

To add a *new* commit to `master`, Git freezes the index into a new snapshot, adds the log message and your name and so on for metadata, and sets the new commit's parent to `C`.  This produces the hash ID for new commit `D`, which Git now writes into the name `master`, giving:

```
A  <-B  <-C  <-D   <--master
```

Since the internal arrows can't change (they're part of commits!), we just need to remember that they always point backwards (leftwards in these drawings).  So at some point we have some commit hash, let's call it `H` for short, at which we create a name `branch-A`:

```
...--H   <-- branch-A
```

If we also create the name `branch-B` now, we have *both* names pointing to `H`:

```
...--H   <-- branch-A, branch-B
```

This means that both branches contain *the same* commits (starting from `H` and working backwards).  The snapshot in `H` will exactly match the snapshot in `H`, of course, down to file modes as well as contents.  So there can be no difference between the two commits.

Hence, if you see different permissions for files when checking out `branch-A` vs when checking out `branch-B`, they must point to *different commits*, otherwise the executable/not-executable flags on the files would match.

However, fixing the permissions in your work-tree (and index) **will not change any existing commits**.  That's literally impossible: Git itself cannot do this.  You can only make new commits.  If you need to fix older commits, you must copy the ones with the wrong permissions to new commits whose main difference is that they have correct permissions:

```
...--H--I--J   <-- branch-A
      \
       K--L   <-- branch-B
```

The permissions are now wrong in commit `J`, and correct in commit `L`: but are they right or wrong in commit `I`, which is also only on `branch-A`?  Do you want to make a new commit that's just like `I`, except with the right permissions?  If you do, you must make a replacement for `J` as well, that's much like `J` but uses `I`'s replacement as its parent.

If it's sufficient to just make a *new* commit on `branch-A` that sets its files to the executable-mode taken from commit `L`, that's relatively trivial.  You will end up with:

```
...--H--I--J--M   <-- branch-A
      \
       K--L   <-- branch-B
```

where commit `M` matches commit `J` in everything except the stored executable bit for each such file.

#### Viewing the modes in any commit

To see the file names and their modes for any given commit, use `git ls-tree` with the `-r` (recursive) option.  Simply identify the commit you want:

```
git ls-tree -r <hash>
```

The output is one line per committed file.  Since Git stores *only* files, the default recursive listing does not include any intermediate sub-trees needed for Git's internal representation, and you'll get a listing of all `blob` objects—these are Git's internal representation for files—except for two special cases: symbolic links and submodules (technically, *gitlinks* at this level).  If you have neither of those, you can ignore the special cases.

The output will resemble this, which is the first part of the output on an actual Git repository (for Git itself):

```
100644 blob 12a89f95f993546888410613458c9385b16f0108    .clang-format
100644 blob 49b30516419c8dfe8c039ef368a3af984439ebcc    .gitattributes
100644 blob 64e605a02b71c51e9f59c429b28961c3152039b9    .github/CONTRIBUTING.md
100644 blob adba13e5baf4603de72341068532e2c7d7d05f75    .github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
```

The first field is the `mode` string.  The second is always `blob` (except for those special cases that you probably don't have, but if you do, filter away any non-"blob" lines).  The third is the internal hash ID for the file's snapshot, and the last field, after a literal ASCII tab character, gives the file's path name as seen in that snapshot.

To get the above, I ran:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD
```

I could also have used `git ls-tree -r master` or `git ls-tree -r f84b9b09d40408cf91bbc500d9f190a7866c3e0f`: all of those identify commit `f84b9b09d40408cf91bbc500d9f190a7866c3e0f`, which is the tip of the `master` branch.  In your case, you can use `git ls-tree -r branch-B` to get all the mode and name items from the tip commit of `branch-B`.

#### Changing work-tree modes and committing

At this point, then, you just need to have the current tip of `branch-A` checked out.  Then, from the modes and names, you can use whatever your computer's "change the mode of the file" command is to set the desired work-tree mode.  `git add` all the updated work-tree files to copy their new modes into the index, and run `git commit`.  If you are on a Linux system, for instance, you can use `chmod` directly (note: this has a small flaw if you have files whose names contain white-space, as `read` won't respect it properly unless you fiddle with `IFS`):

```
git checkout branch-A
git ls-tree -r branch-B | while read mode ftype hash path; do
    [ $ftype = blob ] && chmod "$path" $mode
done
git add -u
git commit
```

This will complain about any files in the commit that `branch-B` names that do not exist in the commit extracted by `git checkout branch-A`.  If you have white-space-named files, you may get errors here as well, so be sure to check.

You can fancy this up as needed, but that's the essence.  Note that if you want to rebuild existing commits, you can use an interactive `git rebase` to do it one commit at a time.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. I'll probably be consulting what you've written here for quite a while, you've made quite a few things much clearer to me. I resolved my issue the long and dirty way, but you've provided a lot of valuable and well-explained information.